# I need help about mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get name and supervisor name

Table name:user

```
id | name |
-----------
 1 | David 
 2 | Frank
 3 | Shane
 4 | Franchich
```

Another table name: details

```
user_id | supervisor_id|
----------------------------
  1 | 4
  2 | 3
  3 | 4
```

I have tried like :

```
select 
    name as user name 
from user, details 
WHERE details.user_id=user.id
```

but failed

Now I want to get result like

```
User Name | Supervisor Name
------------------------------
David | Franchich
Frank | Shane
Shane | Franchich
```

So how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for two JOINs between table details and table user, like :

```
select
    u1.name as user_name,
    u2.name as supervisor_name
from details d
inner  join user u1 on u1.id = d.user_id
inner  join user u2 on u2.id = d.supervisor_id
```

Comment: many many thanks , worked exactly that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should to join for twice to `user` table. You need table alias to identifie `user` as "user" (u) and `user` as "manager" (m):

```
select 
     u.name as UserName, m.username as SupervisorName
from 
     user u
inner join 
     details   on u.id = details.user_id
inner join 
     user m    on details.supervisor_id = m.id
```

Comment: thanks , ur idea is 100% okay